# I need help making my game pause and resume

Tags: java, android, onresume, onpause

I have a game where you click on an image in the centre, and a value increases. When the app is opened, I've made a splash come up before the main activity starts (the clicking screen). However, every time I back out of the app, and click the icon again, it goes through the splash, goes to the main screen, and starts the game again, setting the value back to zero.

My Java for the Splash:

```
package com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle splashBundle) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(splashBundle);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);



    Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent("com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp.CLICKER");
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
            finish();   
            }
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

My Java for the MainClass which is then run:

```
package com.bipbapapps.leagueclickerapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public float goldCount = 0.0f;
Button minionClick;
TextView textGoldCount;
String textTotal;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Set fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);



    //Linking the variables
    minionClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minioncentreid);
    textGoldCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewtop);

    //String which will display at the top of the app
    textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";

    //Setting TextView to the String
    textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);

    //Setting onClickListener
    minionClick.setClickable(true);

    minionClick.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.minioncentreid:
    goldCount += 1.0;
    textTotal = goldCount + " Gold";
    textGoldCount.setText(textTotal);
    break;
    }


}
```

}

Anyone have any idea how to allow my game to pause and resume when it's minimized? Also, is there a way so that when the app is destroyed (properly closed), and restarted, the values for variables are kept? Would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `onBackPress` of the second activity, you should store the score in shared preferences. Every time you come on the `onCreate` of `Splash` activity, retrieve the score value and check if it is set to 0 then show splash screen else goto main activity with current score.

Comment: Remember to set the score back to 0 at the end of a game though.

Comment: @mbs exactly, use sharedpreferences to maintain game state.